# JS string search issue

Tags: javascript, string, search, substring

Searching for a string at the start of another string works OK with this:

```
       if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) { ...
```

I also want to search the second word (following a comma) but the following never returns a hit:

```
findcomma = ($(this).text().indexOf(",")+1); // plus 1 to ignore comma itself
    if ($(this).text().substring(findcomma,$(this).text().length).search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) { ...
```

Help with the second If statement will be appreciated
thanks

Comment: What is exactly the problem? Perhaps the 2nd word doesn't match the `filter` regexp... By the way, if you want to extract the words in a string separated by a comma, you should rather use `$(this).text().split(",")[i]` (i = 0 for the 1st word, i = 1 for the 2nd one, ...)

Comment: its not so much I want to extract as just know the string is there. I can find the string in the first word OK but not in the second string (after the comma). all your rapid responses appreciated!

Comment: Can you thus please add a jsfiddle example, since I don't see any code error there...

Comment: jsfiddel is a new one on me - will sort out how to do it later when back home - meanwhile, your help is appreciated...

Comment: I have provided you an example, showing that it finds the correct word : [sample jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dceXU/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have mismatched the parantheses `()`. Just rewrite the if condition to

```
if (($(this).text().substring(findcomma,$(this).text().length)).search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0)
```

Comment: stf's rewrite has the same error (it does not find the string)